# Why changing cursor position in Vim using /foo is considered a jump but doing so using the w command is not?

Tags: vim

When I move from one word to another by pressing <kbd>w</kbd>, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> doesn't take me to the previous word. Basically, moving from one word to another using the <kbd>w</kbd> command does not create a new entry in `:jumps`.

But when I change the cursor position as a result of a search command (say `/foo`), then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> takes me back to the previous cursor position. In other words, searching for a text creates a new entry in `:jumps`.

How can I understand from `:help` which changes in cursor positions are considered as jumps and which ones are not?

Comment: You seem to suffer from tunnel vision: the answer to your question is a few lines above `:help :jumps`.

Comment: @romainl +1-ed you. You seem to be right. Only after reading your comments, I realized that every help subject (including `:help :jumps`) does not exist in isolation, but it is a part of a bigger help document (`motion.txt` in this case), and reading the entire document offers better understanding of the context of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll find all motions that affect the jump list at `:help jump-motions`:

> A "jump" is one of the following commands: "'", "`", "G", "/", "?", "n",
>   "N", "%", "(", ")", "[[", "]]", "{", "}", ":s", ":tag", "L", "M", "H" and
>   the commands that start editing a new file.

The reason that "short" motions like `w` don't affect the jump list is that it would become less useful; jumps are best used for undoing large navigation around the buffer (e.g. after searching, jumping to the next function, etc.), not when short local moves can be easily undone with an opposite motion (e.g. `w` -> `b`). Note that this locality is not limited to the same line; it applies to line-motions like `j` and `k` as well (though some people prefer to have `j` with a count be recorded in the jump list, which can be done with a mapping).